# Having issue with Facebook debugger not scraping new data

Tags: facebook

I've updated my Meta Description in WordPress (using SEO by Yoast), but Facebook continues to use old data. This is after using the debugger. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the OpenGraph tags, once facebook scans a value and logs it you can't update it without changing the values. I ran into a similar issue before. If you Google search some you'll find explanations from Facebook Support on the matter.

Even running the 'Scrape new data' or whatever the action is it will inform you that you are trying to change xxxxxx value. After my research I ended up changing the meta property value with an extension on the url and Facebook scraped the data and updated it correctly. However all of the page likes were lost in this process.